# Can I add fields to clojure types?

Tags: clojure, types, deftype

Clojure structs can be arbitrarily extended, adding new fields.

Is it possible to extend types (created using deftype) in a similar way?

EDIT: For the benefit future visitors, as Brian pointed out below, this feature is subject to change.

Comment: deftype is still a work in progress, things are subject to change.  See e.g. http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_frm/thread/a8b4a1a00fe8d0f2/2ff645127490228b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you can treat types as maps, you just need to extend clojure.lang.IPersistentMap (an implementation is magically supplied).

```
(deftype A [a b]
  clojure.lang.IPersistentMap)
(A 1 2) ;; => #:A{:a 1, :b 2}
(assoc (A 1 2) :c 3) ;; => #:A{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
```

**Note**

Clojure has since split the semantics of types into `defrecord` and `deftype`. For most application-level programming, you'll want to use records. Conveniently, they automatically provide an implementation of `clojure.lang.IPersistentMap`, no magic necessary.

Comment: This doesn't work in Clojure 1.2, you'll get just get an java.lang.AbstractMethodError, as you would expect without providing any implementation.

Comment: This was valid for an early beta release of Clojure 1.2. I've added a note for mentioning the changes in the final release.